# Convergence in probability may be used to convergence in probability for bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Show that convergence in probability for arbitrary random variables may be reduced to convergence in probability for bounded random variables by the transformation X'=arctanX

> My attempt

arctan is a differentiable invertible continous function from R onto (-90,90) so bounded. if arctan (Xn) converges in probability to arctan(X) then **How can I show Xn converges in probability to X**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$X_n \to X$ in probability if and only if every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  a further subsequence converging almost surely to $X$. Almost sure convergence is preserved by continuous maps. Since $\tan $ and $\arctan$ are continuous the result follows.